# My ball is not moving and staying in the center although it should be moving

Tags: java, jpanel

I am coding a primitive Pong game and I have coded it so for when the ball goes off the left hand side of the screen, it goes to the center of the screen and moves in a random directton. However, upon start the ball always stays in the center and never moves(despite the fact the ball's X coordinate is not less than 0 at start.)

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Color; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Pong extends JPanel
{
  private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
  private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(204, 204, 204);
  private static final Color BALL_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
  private static final Color PRIZE_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
  private static final int BALL_DIAM = 50;
  private static final int PRIZE_DIAM = 25;
  private static final int PRIZE_SHIFT = 10;
  private BufferedImage myImage;
  private Graphics myBuffer;
  private Ball ball;
  private int score1;
  private int score2;
  private Polkadot prize;
  private Bumper bumper;
  private Bumper bumper2;
  private Timer t;
  private int hits;

  public Pong()
  {
    myImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, 1);
    myBuffer = this.myImage.getGraphics();
    myBuffer.setColor(BACKGROUND);
    myBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    ball = new Ball(0, 0, 35, BALL_COLOR);
    ball.jump(400, 400);

    prize = new Polkadot(0, 0, 25, PRIZE_COLOR);
    prize.jump(400, 400);
    bumper = new Bumper(380,70,50,100,Color.RED);

    bumper2 = new Bumper(30,70,50,100,Color.BLUE);

    hits = 0;

    t = new Timer(5, new Listener());
    t.start();

    addMouseListener(new Mouse());

    addKeyListener(new Key());
    setFocusable(true);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
  }

  private class Mouse extends MouseAdapter
  {
    private Mouse() {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
      if (e.isMetaDown())
      {
        ball.setX(e.getX());
        ball.setY(e.getY());
      }
      else if (e.isShiftDown())
      {
       ball.setdx((int)(Math.random() * 11.0D - 6.0D));
       ball.setdy((int)(Math.random() * 11.0D - 6.0D));
      }
      else
      {
        prize.setX(e.getX());
        prize.setY(e.getY());
      }
    }
  }

  private class Key extends KeyAdapter
  {
    private Key() {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
      if ((e.getKeyCode() == 38) && (bumper.getY() > 0)) {
        bumper.setY(bumper.getY() - 10);
      } else if ((e.getKeyCode() == 40) && (bumper.getY() < 438)) {
        bumper.setY(bumper.getY() + 10);
      } else if ((e.getKeyCode() == 87) && (bumper2.getY() > 0)) {
        bumper2.setY(bumper2.getY() - 10);
      } else if ((e.getKeyCode() == 83) && (bumper2.getY() < 438)) {
        bumper2.setY(bumper2.getY() + 10);
      }
    }
  }

  private class Listener implements ActionListener
  {
    private Listener() {}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      myBuffer.setColor(BACKGROUND);
      myBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

      ball.move(400, 400);
      collide(ball, prize);
      BumperCollision.collide(bumper,ball);
      BumperCollision.collide(bumper2,ball);

      ball.draw(myBuffer);
      prize.draw(myBuffer);
      bumper.draw(myBuffer);
      bumper2.draw(myBuffer);
      myBuffer.setColor(Color.red);
      myBuffer.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 24));
      myBuffer.drawString("Count: " + score1, 100, 25);
      if(score1 >= 10)
         myBuffer.drawString("This man is the Legend27", 50, 102);
      if(score2 >= 10)
         myBuffer.drawString("The other man might be the legend27", 160, 102);
      if(ball.getX() < -100)
         score1++;
         ball.setX(208);
         ball.setY(50);
         ball.setdx(20);

      repaint();
    }
  }

  public void collide(Ball b, Polkadot p)
  {
    double dist = distance(b.getX(), b.getY(), p.getX(), p.getY());
    if (dist < 37.0D)
    {
      hits += 1;

      p.jump(400, 400);
    }
  }

  private double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
  {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2.0D) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2.0D));
  }
}
```

Ball:

```
//Name:              Date:
   import java.awt.*;
    public class Ball extends Polkadot
   {
      private double dx;       // pixels to move each time step() is called.
      private double dy;
    // constructors
       public Ball()         //default constructor
      {
         super(200, 200, 50, Color.BLACK);
         dx = Math.random() * 12 - 6;          // to move vertically
         dy = Math.random() * 12 - 6;          // to move sideways
      }
       public Ball(double x, double y, double dia, Color c)
      {
         super(x, y, dia, c);
         dx = Math.random()* 12 - 6;
         dy = Math.random() * 12 - 6;
      }

     //modifier methods 
       public void setdx(double x)        
      {
         dx = x;
      }
       public void setdy(double y)
      {
         dy = y;
      }

      //accessor methods
       public double getdx()             
      {
         return dx;
      }
       public double getdy()
      {
         return dy;
      }

     //instance methods
       public void move(double rightEdge, double bottomEdge)
      {
         setX(getX()+ dx);      // move vert.
         setY(getY()+ dy);     

         if(getX() >= rightEdge - getRadius())  
         {
            setX(rightEdge - getRadius());
            dx = dx * -1; 
         }
         else if(getX() <= getRadius())
         {
          setX(getRadius());
          dx = dx * -1;
         }
         if(getY() >= bottomEdge - getRadius())
         {
          setY(bottomEdge - getRadius());
          dy = dy * -1;
         }
         else if (getY() <= getRadius())
         {
          setY(getRadius());
          dy = dy * -1;
         }
     }
   }
```

Comment: what exactly have tried so far to debug the code?

Comment: It will be much easier to answer your question if you provide minimally complete code - just enough to let us understand and reproduce the bug, but no more. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have changed -100 to 0, change score1 to score2, and I've changed < to <=. Every situation has resulted in the same starting position(in the center, unmoving.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two different values for the position of the ball, first you have x, y which are from your parent class, the name of which I do not know. Then you have the position delta member variables of the Ball class called dx and dy. Since your constructor you call the parent constructor

```
super(x, y, dia, c);
```

Where x, y are 200 respectively and then they are never touched after. My guess is that those hold the true position of your ball and therefore those values need to be set. Use the setters after you create the random delta positions in your Ball constructor like so

```
public Ball(double x, double y, double dia, Color c)
{
     super(x, y, dia, c);
     dx = Math.random()* 12 - 6;
     dy = Math.random() * 12 - 6;
     setX(getX() + dx); //add your x difference
     setY(getY() + dy); //add your y difference  
}
```

This should now add your deltas to the Ball object on creation and when it gets painted for the first time it will have a random position on your game board every time a Ball gets created.

How about this line inside the actionPerformed()

```
if(ball.getX() < -100)
    score1++;
    ball.setX(208);
    ball.setY(50);
    ball.setdx(20);
```

If the setters should be called only when ball.getX() < -100 then you need to use brackets with your if. No brackets after an if only executes the next line, and nothing more.

```
if(ball.getX() < -100)
{
    score1++;
    ball.setX(208);
    ball.setY(50);
    ball.setdx(20);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contributions, but I do not think it is necessary to put the setX and setY functions in the ball, only the move() which i use in my actionPerformed to randomly move the ball.Furthermore, when I out the setters in the Ball, the same bug occurs.

Comment: how about the edits?? i added another suggestion @HarrisLew

Comment: Thank you so much @RAZ_Muh_Taz... such a simple mistake that I missed... forgetting the brackets(the other code lines didn't execute!!) I thank you so much for helping me(a neophyte) out.

Comment: you're welcome, good luck with your future coding endeavors! @HarrisLew